# Errors with android:id fields in layouts not anymore recognized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-databinding

Following an upgrade of android-studio, kotlin plugins and sourceCompatibility to Java 8 in an android project, many layout ids are not any more recognized (but strangely not all).
It looks like field name with underscores are not recognized in binding.

For instance:
whith the following declaration in the layout

```xml
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/alert_hist_item__equipement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5px"
            android:text="@string/Device"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
```

in the code

```kotlin
alert_hist_item__equipement.text = "x"
```

is not recognized but

```kotlin
alertHistItemEquipement.text = "x"
```

is recognized.

If I change the field names in the layouts to equivalent camel case names (either only in the code, with the names in the layout still having underscores; or both in code and layout) the fields are recognized.

It is so painful for many reasons:

1. I have dozens of layouts all with id names containing underscore
2. I find names with underscore easier to read (and my team too)
3. it was never specified that android:id fields should follow certain rules

is this possible to change that behavior ? Could it be a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Please add following `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to you app level gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

According to Kotlin documentation they are deprecated but they are still working for me.

As and alternate they provide us with data and view binding. For you `View Binding` should work!

here is the example:

add following to your app level gradle:

```
buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
```

then in you activity declare as following (Assuming you activity name is ManuelYguel)

```
class ManuelYguel : AppCompatActivity() {
     private lateinit var binding: ActivityManuelYguelBinding

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityManuelYguelBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.alertHistItemEquipement.text = "x"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a sad and unfortunate constraint that comes from the new autogenerated binding class. This is specified in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions
it says:

> Note: The binding class converts IDs to camel case.